# Classic asp or phonegap

Tags: android, asp.net, cordova

I have a question that keeps me in confusion.. I have knowledge in classic asp and phonegap development. I am now confused to choose the right one for my career. People say classic asp is outdated. But I get opportunities in classic asp even now. But if I choose phonegap , will I have a good opportunity in future.? It is a strange questions  but kindly suggest me friends ..

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap and Cordova developing is based on front-end coding , the asp classic and php and ... is not supported .
If you have skilled in front-end development like HTML CSS JS JQUERY , it is fine to use cordova and phonegap for app development.